# AzureRM Add-AzureRmADGroupMember failing

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-rm

I am trying to add a service principal from a Web App (Managed Service Identity) in to an Azure AD group and can't figure out why I am getting an error. I am using AzureRM 6.0.1. Any idea where I may be going wrong?

**PowerShell Command:**

```
Add-AzureRmADGroupMember -MemberObjectId 3cc2d09c-4fd4-4251-aa42-9ad6a0440606 -TargetGroupObjectId 2ca727c0-e2ec-46d4-9202-2144d83eb6b5 -PassThru
```

**Error:**

> Add-AzureRmADGroupMember : The URI
>   'https://graph.windows.net//Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureTenant/directoryObj
>   ects/3cc2d09c-4fd4-4251-aa42-9ad6a0440606' is not valid since it is
>   not based on
>   'https://graph.windows.net/fdfed904-9e03-4e17-89c4-61053e0777be/'. At
>   line:2 char:2
>   +  Add-AzureRmADGroupMember -MemberObjectId 3cc9d09c-4fd4-4251-aa42-9ad ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Add-AzureRmADGroupMember], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.AddAzureADGroupMemberCommand

Comment: I'm encountering an identical issue and would love an answer

Comment: same here - just posted the question to the PS Gallery directly: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Resources/6.1.0